# download of template 'org.springframework.templates.mvc' failed

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-security, spring-tool-suite

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting this

```
error : download of template 'org.springframework.templates.mvc' failed.
```

Whenever i try to create a spring *MVC* project using Spring tool suite ?

I'm a newbie to spring. please guide me in setting this up.

Comment: How's your network? Sluggish? Behind a proxy (Eclipse has global proxy settings)? P.S. those old samples are kind of obsolete (the Starter Project, or Getting Started Guides, are available in the latest STS and are more up to date).

Answer (score 0):

May be you are behind the proxy.

Go to `window -> preferences -> general -> network connections`

Choose `Active Provider - Manual`

Under `Proxy bypass tab - Add Host` and add the `proxy server IP or name`.

Also add maven proxy settings in `settings.xml`

Now the template will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

changing "Active Provider" to "Direct" worked for me

Go to **window -> preferences -> general -> network connections**

Choose **Active Provider - Direct**